# How find minimum and maximum relative with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ubuntu, scikit-learn

How it is possible to find relative minimum and maximum values in a columns of a pandas data frame?

I know how to find the min and max value but I don't find any specific function? Is it necessary to implement a specific function?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to code the function to apply it on a pandas dataframe. Pandas brings all kinds of functions in its package. Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

For instance, here is the function to find the maximum:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html

Comment: thank you very much, very clear and useful...unfortunately I had -2 in question from someone

Answer (score 1):

Use dataframe.describe() function to view summary statistics which has min,max, mean,etc.